# My SQL Query Won't work for some reason (ReCAPTCHA 2.0)

Tags: php, post, mysqli, recaptcha, captcha

So I'm using RECAPTCHA 2.0 and I can't seem to get this form to work without getting a SQL Query Error, If you can find a solution please reply and thanks.
(I've made the secret key secret)

Can't seem to post PHP Code here so here is a pastebin link - https://pastebin.com/CbMhKVPf

```
<?php
$link = "https://pastebin.com/CbMhKVPf";
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**  You should also check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out exactly why it's failing. "SQL query error" means absolutely nothing without context.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work, just had some logic errors.